# How to read DjVu files on Kindle?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, kindle-paperwhite, djvu, apps

I want to be able to read DjVu files on my kindle.  I don't want to convert DjVu to PDF or MOBI.  Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What version of Kindle do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Document Viewer](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.sufficientlysecure.viewer/) (fork of the now defunct EBookDroid). It's also [on the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.viewer).

Comment: How exactly does it allow reading on Kindle?

Comment: @fnt Document Viewer displays PDFs, DjVus, etc. Is Kindle not Android-based? Can you not install Android apps on Kindle devices?

Comment: The question is obviously not about Kindle Fire.